# How to use major tick marks in chart.js 2.9.3?

Tags: javascript, canvas, charts, html5-canvas, chart.js

I use latest Chart.js **2.9.3**. I've tried the following code with major ticks:

```js
        var ctx = document.getElementById('chart').getContext('2d');
        var chart  = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'horizontalBar',

            data: {
                datasets: [{
                    barPercentage: 0.2,
                    borderColor: 'black',
                    borderWidth: 2,
                    borderSkipped: false,
                    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                    data: [[0, 8000]]
                }]
            },

            options: {
                legend: false,
                tooltips: false,
                animation: false,
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    fontSize: '26',
                    text: 'AT1G24460'
                },
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        position: 'top',
                        offset: true,
                        ticks: {
                            major: {
                                enabled: true,
                                fontColor: 'red'
                            }
                        },
                        gridLines: {
                            drawOnChartArea: false
                        }
                    }],
                    yAxes: [{
                        display: false                        
                    }]
                }
            }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
 <div class="text-center">
        <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
</div>
```

The result is the following (major ticks are not displayed at all). So how to make major tick marks work in chart.js?

P.S. My final goal is to have top axis like this:
[image]

What axis styling is possible without direct canvas painting (ticks below axis baseline, first and last ticks are enlarged, two labels for first and last ticks, no labels except fof first and last tick, etc.)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I could not find that ticks -> major in the official documentation, closest I found is: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/labelling.html but even there they say `The third parameter passed to the callback function is an array of labels, but in the time scale, it is an array of {label: string, major: boolean} objects.` I just tried and that is not the case ... seems buggy, I would be looking for another chart provider or even build my own

Comment: @HelderSepulveda major ticks are documented at [https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/styling.html](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/styling.html) inside `Major Tick Configuration` section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Official answer](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/7355#issuecomment-628709697):

> Major ticks are only supported on the time scale in 2.9. In 3.0 they
>   are also being added to the log scale. They're not in the linear scale
>   yet. But major ticks are most useful for deciding which ticks not to
>   skip in the autoSkipper. 3.0 will also add better support for tick
>   styling via scriptable tick options ([#7337](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/7337)), which will allow you to
>   make ticks that you want bolder, bigger, different colors, etc. and
>   you don't need major tick support for that. I'd recommend trying 3.0